# Return current via

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, pcb-layers, via

I have a 4 layer board.

1. Layer 1 (Top):  SIGNAL + GND plane
2. Layer 2:  whole GND plane (no tracks)
3. Layer 3:  whole power plane (no tracks)
4. Layer 4: (Bottom):  SIGNAL + GND plane

After putting vias from Layer 1 to Layer 4 I also put ground vias for a return current.

How close can I put return current ground vias?

In this picture I have a UART connection, but speaking generally (for all protocols, SPI, QSPI, etc.) which picture is correct?

[image]

A second one:

[image]

Comment: If you can put a via within the flood exclusion area without breaking design rules then surely you can flood closer to the central via.

Comment: @Andyaka in " flood exclusion area ' - do you mean black circle area around UART8_TX via ?

Comment: @Alatriste It depends on your signal bit rate (frequency), signal edge slew rate, and how long tracks these are. For QSPI the frequencies can be near 100 MHz where this matters. For the UART, which baud rates you intend to use? For about 100 Kbps you might not need any return vias, for 12 MBps it might start to be a good idea. So generally speaking, for these protocols you speak of, the via placement may be irrelevant which you use, or it might be irrelevant if it's even there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't sweat it, UART signals aren't nearly fast enough to worry about per-via signal quality measures like this.  Just stitch evenly.

I wouldn't even bother with top/bottom GND, just use GND and VDD inner layers.

The signal quality difference simply simply won't be measurable, at least not without a precision VNA, and only by upper harmonics of the clock rate in use.

(Q)SPI generally has a higher data rate than UART, but the signaling is identical, and so too the signal quality.  With respect to emissions, there will be an impact, only to the extent that there are more signals that might change simultaneously (QSPI), and more often (50Mbps+?).  Simply placing the vias underneath a component that already has stitching and supply bypass vias will suffice.

---

Operating assumptions:

- Very ordinary embedded application: small to medium board (~10 cm across?), average-capability MCU (1-5ns edge rate), 3.3V or so logic levels
- CPU clock up to maybe 200MHz ballpark, peripheral clock maybe a modest fraction thereof
- Not concerned about source termination (that goes at the source, not en route as here)
- Not concerned about cables/connectors (filtering/protection should be used near them, not en route)
- Stitching is present to short out* any between-planes or ground-loop coupling or radiation (e.g. patch antenna modes) that might affect signal quality of nearby traces, or emissions of the system
- Stitching includes bypass caps between ground(s) and supply(ies), distributed more or less across the board
- The system is laid out more-or-less reasonably, respecting signal quality, providing adequate grounding, and has modest extents (again, a "very ordinary embedded application")
- Commercial test levels apply (or would apply, if this would be tested at all)

*Meaning, attenuating to below some desired/required margin.

EMC is a holistic field of study, i.e., total knowledge of the complete extended system is required.  That is, everything that is connected to the circuit in question, and nearby subjected to its fields; or including up until a suitable cutting plane, across which assumptions must be stipulated.

There is essentially nothing meaningful we can say about a 2 x 2 mm section of a PCB, that relates to the fields at a distance from that PCB, or the system it is embedded within.  I have listed the most significant assumptions above, but if any of them do not match, beware this answer need not apply.

Comment: It is good you added the assumptions. Because QSPI could be very high frequency and requires careful planning of return paths and maybe impedance control. The UART could also be tens of megabits and we don't know that. It all depends on both the slew rate and the bit rate to figure out signal integrity.

Comment: It is an answer pattern that I would like to see, well, *at all*, but complaining about that will accomplish nothing.  So I am being the change I want to see.  FWIW, under the assumptions, I wouldn't care about 10s of Mbit for either case, and might be concerned if QSPI is pushing 100+. But indeed, there are many exceptions that may apply, and askers need to be aware *just how many ways* EMC can vary for better and for worse.

Comment: @TimWilliams so there is no direct answer , I have to do a lot of measurements and simulations to correctly put vias for QSPI

Comment: @Alatriste Given the question you have asked, given the assumptions above, and given my knowledge of the subject, I don't see that there are many (perhaps any) more direct answers than this. Indeed, EMC knowledge is hard won through basic theoretical study, and simulations and measurements (and few even do those!). It's not an *impossible* topic, but it does take years of study to reach an understanding of it, and I'm afraid there isn't much I can do to further that study here -- other than to give words of encouragement, to keep studying, and keep trying.